# how to merge response of a paginated rest service in mule

Tags: rest, pagination, mule

In `mule` flow, I need to call a `paginated` `rest service`. Am planning to use `for each` component incrementing page number for each `http outbound call` till no more results are returned.

Question is how to aggregate the responses of all these calls together? Need to `FTP` one big result to client.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your scenario correct, you are already using the solution - `FOR-EACH` .

For each after processing all your Paginated Rest calls provides a collection of the responses  received from the rest calls.

So you can iterage those responses and aggregate them and then FTP.

If you are looking for an out-of-box aggregator of the output from For-Each, then I am not sure if Mule has one.

Hope this helps.

[Mule ForEach example](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Foreach)

Comment: **For each after processing all your Paginated Rest calls provides a collection of the responses received from the rest calls.** How can I access the collection of responses?

Comment: After completing the for-each  #[payload] gives you the collection of responses.